# How can I correctly find a .txt file and read it's contents using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, electron

I am building an Electron application and I have a logs.txt file which I want to read the contents of and put it on an HTML page. I'm using NodeJS and the "fs" module but the following code is giving me the error "Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory..."

I think the issue may lie in the reference of it. Here's the code below:

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('file://' + __dirname + '/logs.txt', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = data;
});
```

In the error it shows me the exact location of the file. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file:///Users/MY_USER_ACCOUNT/files/code/git/MY_APP/src/usr/logs.txt'
```

This is exactly where the logs.txt file is, but for some reason it still says that there's no such file there.

I'm on a Mac if that is relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: Please vote up answers that are helpful and well-researched. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

### Use a path, not a URL

`fs.readFile` expects a file path if passed a `string` as argument.

You’re passing it a `file://` URL `string` instead. Remove `file://`.

#### Pass the file’s content encoding

You also want to pass the file’s encoding to `fs.readFile`:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/logs.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = data;
});
```

(Are you sure you want to read `logs.txt` relative to the location of your JavaScript source file?)

#### Use Promises

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const data = await fs.readFile(__dirname + '/logs.txt', 'utf-8')
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `file://` format, you need to create a `URL` object to pass to `fs.readFile()` like this rather than just passing it as a string:

```
const fileUrl = new URL('file://' + __dirname + '/logs.txt');
fs.readFile(fileUrl, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = data;
});
```

See the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_url_object_support)

Comment: Where do you find this documented?  Can you point to a reference?

Comment: The link is added to the answer  - thanks for the reminder

Comment: Well, what I'm asking is why can't one just use a normal path such as  `__dirname + '/logs.txt'`?  Why use an URL at all? That's how I've always used the `fs` module.   Is there something peculiar about doing this in electron?

Comment: You certainly can. The interface supports both, but a url format, but the URL format  is standardized and not operating system dependent. You are free from worrying too much about path separator differences like using \\ on Windows.

Comment: Well, there's no `//` issues in `path.join(__dirname, 'logs.txt')` which is how you do this with OS independence.  I still don't see why one would use a file URL for such a simple operation.  Yes, I see that it works.  I just don't see why one would do it that way.

Comment: If you are building the path rather than already formatting it like `__dirname + “\\folder\\logs\\” + filename` things can get more awkward. I prefer using `file://` because it’s more consistent, but if you already have the path formatted it is not wrong to use a simple string.

Comment: My least favorite part of file URLs on Windows is when they starting containing drive letters or UNC volume names.  Things get messy in a hurry.  Anyway, I see your point, just not my preference.

Comment: TIL that readFile acceps a URL object - thanks @AlwaysLearning :)